# Pi with touchscreen as macro keyboard

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen

Has anyone ever tried or thought of using the Raspberry Pi and a touchscreen as a macro/shortcut second keyboard?  I was thinking of something like this [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08VNCLDTK?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08VNCLDTK) and this https://www.instructables.com/Second-Keyboard-for-Macros/ I could sit next to my desk and program to do...well...anything.  Has anyone tried this or has any input on why this might not work?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1565915/how-to-set-up-a-rpi-to-act-as-a-usb-slave-device has some info you may want if you wish to make a pi a keyboard, mouse, and/or game controller.  You can also look into bluetooth...

Comment: `Has anyone ever tried?` is not a question about Raspberry Pi